# Fedora 20 Heartbleed openssl fix

Tags: openssl, fedora

I am just trying to fix the Heartbleed bug associated with OpenSSL on Fedora Core 20. I am trying to follow the instructions as described here:

http://www.forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=298372

That is, installing packages as follows:

```
yum -y install koji
koji download-build --arch=x86_64 openssl-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1
yum localinstall openssl-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64.rpm
```

However, I keep on running into this error:

```
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
       Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-37.fc20.1
       Installed: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
           openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-37.fc20
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
           openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-30.fc20
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried installing openssl-libs separately but I run into this error:

```
Error: Package: 1:cups-libs-1.7.1-8.fc20.i686 (@updates)
       Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
Error: Package: VirtualGL-2.3.3-2.fc20.i686 (@fedora)
       Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
Error: Package: 1:cups-libs-1.7.1-8.fc20.i686 (@updates)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libcrypto.so.10
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libcrypto.so.10
Error: Package: VirtualGL-2.3.3-2.fc20.i686 (@fedora)
       Requires: libssl.so.10
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libssl.so.10
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libssl.so.10
Error: Package: libssh2-1.4.3-8.fc20.i686 (@fedora)
       Requires: libssl.so.10
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libssl.so.10
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libssl.so.10
Error: Package: 1:cups-libs-1.7.1-8.fc20.i686 (@updates)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: trousers-0.3.11.2-3.fc20.i686 (@updates)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libcrypto.so.10
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libcrypto.so.10
Error: Package: VirtualGL-2.3.3-2.fc20.i686 (@fedora)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libcrypto.so.10
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libcrypto.so.10
Error: Package: trousers-0.3.11.2-3.fc20.i686 (@updates)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: VirtualGL-2.3.3-2.fc20.i686 (@fedora)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: 1:cups-libs-1.7.1-8.fc20.i686 (@updates)
       Requires: libssl.so.10
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libssl.so.10
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libssl.so.10
Error: Package: VirtualGL-2.3.3-2.fc20.i686 (@fedora)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)
Error: Package: libssh2-1.4.3-8.fc20.i686 (@fedora)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: libssh2-1.4.3-8.fc20.i686 (@fedora)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libcrypto.so.10
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libcrypto.so.10
Error: Package: trousers-0.3.11.2-3.fc20.i686 (@updates)
       Requires: libssl.so.10
       Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.i686 (@updates)
           libssl.so.10
       Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64 (/openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64)
           Not found
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.i686 (fedora)
           libssl.so.10
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software versions, administration and patching. Server Fault has quite a few questions on the topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed.

Comment: you may want to look at [unix.se]. I've flagged for migration.

Answer (score 3):

The patch is in Fedora 20 stable now.  A simple

```
# yum update
```

as root will fix your problem, or

```
$ sudo yum update
```

If you prefer not to run around as root

And to answer the other answer above, the fix was backported from the 1.0.1g branch into 1.0.1e for Fedora.  Ref [here](http://major.io/2014/04/07/openssl-heartbleed-updates-for-fedora-19-and-20/) for details.

Do not forget to **reboot**, either the affected services, preferably the whole box. Not doing so will still leave you vulnerable.

#### Testing sites:

- http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/
- https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

To put back OT: The fix above did note that if you have openssl-libs (same version), that you may have to grab those as a local compile as well.

Answer (score 2):

I thought that 1.01e was a problem?

From Life Hacker and other sites: "The Heartbleed bug, as its now known, affects any sites and services running specific versions of OpenSSL (1.0.1 through 1.0.1f)"

Comment: To be fair, Thawte SSL toolbox (and likely others) still marks my site as vulnerable, even though it has been patched by Fedora.

Comment: Looks like openssl-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1 IS the right patched version accoring to this; https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/announce/2014-April/003205.html

Comment: Someone forgot to restart the affected services (that would be me). D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
sudo yum localinstall openssl-libs-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64.rpm  openssl-1.0.1e-37.fc20.1.x86_64.rpm
```

above all on **one** line.

I.e. install both ssl and libs at same time and circular dependency is resolved.

Got this from https://library.linode.com/security/openssl-heartbleed